# How to change resolution on Dune network media player blindly?

Tags: media-player

Can someone please help me? I run into a problem that seems unsolvable. I have a Dune network media player hd base 3.0 and it is connected to TV with a HDMI.

I have changed the resolution in the setup. The TV does not recognise that resolution so it is now blank. I can not see the menu of the Dune media player on my TV, it reads HDMI: unsupported resolution.

The problem is I can not change it back as I do not see any menu on the TV. How can I change this resolution? I have tried turning on/off. I have tried changing settings on the TV.

Ideas so far:
-Can someone tell me how to force a reset on the Dune network player?
-Can someone tell me (step by step, button by button) how to change the resolution to something common?
-Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
Turn on, wait till ready.
Press the mode button on remote. Wait till finished. Repeat mode press, wait each time. At a time it will reach 720p, that is good for my TV.

Remember next time when changing resolution, do not press anything (will undo in 30sec automaticall) :)